# Assign "True" to for loop containing an if statement that triggers an email if the for loop is True

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

```
mylist = [right_branchcode, right_branchname, right_sellingcode, right_advcorp, right_childparent, \
      right_eliteCategoryId, right_partyid, right_retailmga]
for item in mylist:
      if len(item) > 0:
         print(item)
      else:
        print()
```

I want to be able to return "True" if the for loop prints an item. The ultimate goal is to trigger an email notification that also includes the print(item) within it. I just dont know how to assign an operator to a for loop which contains an if statement.

I hope this is clear. Im still learning and find it hard to express what I need sometimes.

Thanks

Comment: The question isnt clear, need more information, however to my understanding you are trying to return true if item is printed. Ans:`put the loop in a function by passing my_list as a parameter,then you can return inside if statement after printing the item.`

Comment: You cannot assign an operator to a for loop; a for loop only iterates it does not return anything. If you want to do something when the condition is True, do it in the if's suite.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if i understood it correctly, but you can simply assign a variable inside the if statement.

```
mylist = [right_branchcode, right_branchname, right_sellingcode, right_advcorp, right_childparent, \
      right_eliteCategoryId, right_partyid, right_retailmga]
for item in mylist:
      if len(item) > 0:
         print(item)
         bool_var = True
      else:
        print()
print(bool_var) # It will print true if item is found
```

You can also use `return` inside it, or `break` if you want to stop the loop when it finds the item.

Comment: This might give a `NameError` (or `UnboundLocalError` if in a function) if `bool_var` never gets to be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The loop itself isn't true or false; it's a flow-control statement, not an expression. What you are looking for is a *flag* (a Boolean-valued variable) whose value indicates whether or not a non-empty value was printed.

```
mylist = [...]
printed_something = False
for item in mylist:
    if item:
        print(item)
        printed_something = True
    else:
        print()
```

After the loop completes, you can use the value of `printed_something` as necessary. It will only have been changed to `True` if at least one non-empty value was seen during the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable to False before the loop.  Inside the loop, if you print anything, then set that variable to True.  Finally, after the loop finishes, return the variable.

```
mylist = [... stuff ...]
myflag = False
for item in mylist:
    if len(item) > 0:
        print(item)
        myflag = True
    else:
        print()
return myflag
```

Comment: Thank you I will use this in future!

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to just execute the code you want (e.g. send or do not send email) inside the loop. However, if you *really* want to separate concerns and have the email-sending logic separate from the iterating logic, you can use a generator. This corresponds to the notion of having an iterator return (`yield`) a value.

```
mylist = [...]

def iterate_over_list(l):
    for item in l:
        if len(item) > 0:
            yield True


item_iterator = iterate_over_list(mylist)

for item in item_iterator:
    if item:
        print('Send email') # replace with email-sending code
    else:
        print("Don't send email")
```

Comment: You said in your question that ultimately you would implement some code to send an email when the condition in your loop was true. That's accessory to your question which is about returning a value from a loop, so I replaced it with a print statement as an indication. If you need help sending an email with Python, that's a matter for another question (which has almost certainly been asked before on stackoverflow)